# What are the "native" Ubuntu Mainline Kernel?

Tags: kernel

I've found a directory  named "native" within the Ubuntu Mainline Kernels.
Here it is: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/native/

What are the differences between the mainline/native/v4.8-rc6 compared to the mainlien/v4.8-rc6?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are identical debs now in both directories.

Comment: why is 'native' used then?

Comment: The patches applied are different (well a few are the same) and the kernel configuration (a patch) is different, with one based on 4.8.0-8.9 and the other based on 4.8.0-9.10. Also notice that the native builds all failed.